# WP_CONTENT_DIR disables plugin directory

Tags: plugins

I have mutlisite that, which after migration generates `file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.`, even though the open_basedir settings in ISPConfig for open_basedir are correct.

FYI, open_basedir settings are a php.ini option that limits a website's php execution to allowed directories.

ISPConfig is a server control panel.

After reading, I discovered that the cause of this is usually bad upload paths from previous server locations, therefore I tried to fix this problem by using:

`define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/web/wp-content/' );` #my wp install is inside a jailkit

While this solution works for the content, which works no problem, it simultaneously disables all of my plugins which are located at /web/wp-content/plugins.

**clarification**: by disable, I meant wp actually believes that the plugin directory doesn't exist and therefore shows the content as it would with all plugins disabled.

Therefore I tried to following to define the plugin directory, but WP seems to ignore it and the problem persists.

`define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/web/wp-content/plugins' );`

Any tips? thx

Comment: so plugins can no longer be activated after adding the define? What happens when you try to activate them? Or is it just that you want to change the `wp-content` folder and don't want plugins to be deactivated when that happens? What is jailkit? What are `open_basedir` and `ISPConfig`?

Comment: I edited my answer.  My solution now gets plugins & themes to work properly...  however, I am still getting an open_basedir restrictions error for "wp-includes/load.php on line 545"  Any tips on how to resolve it?  I will start it as necessary.

Comment: I clarified my question a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

@tom-j-nowell  Thanks for your reply...  Late last, night I finally cracked the problem using this solution, which I advise everyone to add to their dev notes if you have to migrate wp sites:

solution:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/' );
 define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins' );
```

In my case, I migrated a multisite from a LAMP environment that previously had the usual root path `/var/www/html/wordpress-directory/wp-content` to an ISPConfig jailkit environment `/web/wordpress-directory/wp-content`.